# How to assign image in HTML file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am using following way to open the image in light box but it opens the image which is selected i want that when i click any image it should open another images how to do this

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".linkbutton").click(function(){
            var address= $(this).attr("src");
            $("#popup").fadeIn("slow");
            $("#lightbox").attr("src",address);
        });
        $("#close").click(function(){
            $("#popup").fadeOut("fast");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Following in body

```
<div>
    <img src="image/smallicon_2.png" class="linkbutton">
</div> 

<div id="popup">
    <div id="center">
        <img id="lightbox" src="image/popup_page_1.png" >
        <img id="close" src="images/close.png" alt="close" >
    </div>  <!-- #center --> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an attribute in the image element to reference the new image:

```
<img src="image/smallicon_2.png" class="linkbutton" data-light="image/bigimage_2.png" />
```

Then replace:

```
var address= $(this).attr("src");
```

with:

```
var address= $(this).attr("data-light");
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the line that determines the src of the image

```
var address= $(this).attr("src");
```

So it uses the src of the image you want.

Comment: i am using this code for 3 image like i have two button and for each i want different so how will i aasing in this it will get only for one image